# Creating a density plot out of a large matrix in octave

Tags: octave, mesh, density-plot, octave-gui

I'm trying to create a density plot with a file I have been given, where the matrix is a 663 x 676 grid that shows the height at points across a physical piece of silicon. I am supposed to use this matrix to construct a picture of the silicon's surface.

I am trying to create a 3d image of the surface of the silicon using the code:

```
clear all
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
data = fscanf(fid, '%f');
A = reshape(data, 663,676);
M = 1:663;
N = 1:676;
Z = A(M,N);
mesh(M,N,Z)
```

It gives me:
error: surface: rows (Z) must be the same as length (Y) and columns (Z) must be the same as length (X)
error: called from
surface>**surface** at line 136 column 11
surface at line 68 column 21
mesh at line 84 column 12
M1Q1 at line 8 column 1

What can I do to make it work, to display a 3d map of the silicon's surface?

Comment: Just like [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) says: `mesh(x,y,z)`, where `x` matches the columns (2nd dimension) of `z`, and `y` the rows. So in your case: `mesh(N,M,Z)`.